# Create standard default tasks in custom list when creating Document Set

Tags: document-set

I'd be grateful for any guidance that the group could give on the following:

We are using distinct document sets to create documents and folders associated with each specific phase of a standard project process.

We have a single custom project task list set up to hold tasks associated with projects (we have a columns to define the project for each task), so we can easily produce task MI across all projects and not have to aggregate project specific lists.

We would like to have a standard set of base default project tasks for a phase that are copied into the custom project task list when the document set for a phase is created - is there a way to do this without automating something through SharePoint designer?

Thanks in anticipation

Andy Thomas